# Console is not supported for a recorded stack frame, in debug mode

Tags: ios, stack-trace, xcode7.3, debug-backtrace

I am not able to backtrace using the `bt` command in debug mode after crash. I have searched but did not get the solution. I have tried `[NSThread callStackSymbols]`, but it gives the same message in console:

> Console is not supported for a recorded stack frame

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I think maybe enqueued (grayed) call stacks are not available?

Comment: reset the simulator.

Comment: I'm having this issue too.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing wrong with your Xcode, you just need to select the appropriate instance from the debug navigator, like this.

[image]

To open the gif, follow this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYOeY.gif

Comment: But why can't I use lldb in those frames?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by resetting simulator and quitting Xcode and run it again. Let me know if you still face the issue.